# How to get the content of nested Parentheses in groups

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string such that every array element would have characters between open and close parenthesis.
let me just show:

```
myString = "(2*((3-2)+(5-3)))"
```

So my array should have values like that:

```
myArray[0] = 2*((3-2)+(5-3));

myArray[1] = (3-2)+(5-3);

myArray[2] = (3-2);

myArray[3] = (5-3);
```

I tried to do that by using .split() but it didn't work out as expected. I'm kinda new to the whole RegEx topic

This is my latest approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i <sb.length() ; i++) {
            if(sb.charAt(i)=='('){
                open=i;
                between=0;
                end=0;
                for (int j = i+1; j <sb.length() ; j++) {
                    if(sb.charAt(j)=='('){
                        between++;
                    }
                }for (int x = i+1; x <sb.length() ; x++) {
                    if(sb.charAt(x)==')'){
                        end++;
                    }
                    if(end==between){
                        a.add(sb.substring(open,x+2));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide the code? You will more likely get an answer, if people see that you alredy tried it yourself.

Comment: oh i forgot that, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make this with regexp, but without regex I would think of something like this:

```
    private void findBetweenNestedBrackets(String input, List<String> matches) {
    if(input.contains("(")) {
        int firstBracket = input.indexOf("(") + 1;
        int lastBracket = input.lastIndexOf(")");
        if(firstBracket > lastBracket) {
            String firstInsideBracket = input.substring(0, lastBracket);
            String secondInsideBracket = input.substring(firstBracket);
            matches.add(firstInsideBracket);
            matches.add(secondInsideBracket);
            findBetweenNestedBrackets(firstInsideBracket, matches);
            findBetweenNestedBrackets(secondInsideBracket, matches);
        } else {
            String insideBracket = input.substring(firstBracket, lastBracket);
            matches.add(insideBracket);
            findBetweenNestedBrackets(insideBracket, matches);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    final String input = "(2*((3-2)+(5-3)))";
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    findBetweenNestedBrackets(input, matches);
    matches.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This solution is not perfect, it will print this:

> 2*((3-2)+(5-3))
>
> (3-2)+(5-3)
>
> 3-2)+(5-3  *I assume this is not what you wanted, but you can get rid of such later*
>
> 3-2
>
> 5-3

but I belive its close to what you are trying to achive.